# How to show the plan in the top of each slide with beamer?

Tags: beamer, luatex

I did a presentation with beamer, in the top of each slide there is the title of the section, but I need that it shows all the sections, and highlight the current section

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext, subfig}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Contexte}
    \large

    Les utilisateurs du web veulent accéder à une information

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several themes which have a navigation bar with all sections. You can find an overview at https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

One example with the miniframes outer theme:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext, subfig}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Contexte}
    \large

    Les utilisateurs du web veulent accéder à une information

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the command

```
\usetheme{Luebeck}
```

also you can use the Malmoe, dresden theme